# Copy paste formula till the last row and last column

Tags: excel, vba, row

I have this code, and not so sure as were am i wrong, the idea is to input formula till the last row and last column. the range of last row and column is dynamic. Any suggestion.

```
Sub Countdata()
Dim dERow As Double
Dim lECol As Long

dERow = Cells(10000, 4).End(xlUp).Row
lECol = Cells(10000, 5).End(xlUp).Row
'lECol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
Cells(4, 5).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Actual DailyData'!$B:$B,$D4,'Actual DailyData'!$A:$A,E$3)"
Cells(4, 5).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(4, 5), Cells(4, 5 + lECol)) '- 1))

On Error Resume Next
Range(Cells(4, 5), Cells(4, 5 + lECol)).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(4, 5), Cells(dERow, 5 + lECol))
```

Comment: Could you please be more detailed with the excact task of the macro ? I believe I'm not totally aware of what it should behave like.

Comment: The task is it will apply formula till the last row and last column, eg:- if the column D has the last row till row no 7 and the column is till G, then the formula will be applied from D8 till G8, as row no 6 will be headers

Comment: @MaMe, any update?

Answer (score 0):

Have found the alternative, and is working perfectly:

```
Sub Countdata()
Dim last_row, last_col As Long

last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
last_col = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(4, 5), Cells(last_row, last_col)).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Actual DailyData'!$B:$B,$D4,'Actual DailyData'!$A:$A,E$3)"

End Sub
```